# Links don't fade away after clicking with jQuery fadeout

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://example.com">

<img class="bcvc_ad1" src="http://bdeas.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/ad1.jpg" alt="ad1" width="80" height="80" />

</a>
<script>
  $( ".bcvc_ad1" ).click(function() {
    $( ".bcvc_ad1" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
      // Animation complete.
    });
  });
</script>
```

[Link](http://www.bdeas.com/tester)

Seems to not fadeaway when clicked. Problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify your 
Image with an id, not with a class name.
That's the error. Fadeout works with ids as you can see in the following link

For more information, look [here](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/).

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly.